# How to do conditional check twice in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, boolean

I have a React component as shown. I am passing prop `hasItems` and based on this boolean value, i am showing PaymentMessage Component or showing AddItemsMessage component.

```
export const PayComponent = ({
  hasItems
}: props) => {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      {hasItems ? (
        <PaymentMessage />
      ) : (
        <AddItemsMessage />
      )}
      <Alerts
        errors={errors}
      />
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
```

This works well. Now, i need to pass another prop (paymentError). So based on this, i modify the JSX as below. I will highlight the parts i am adding by using comment section so it becomes easy to see.

```
export const PayComponent = ({
  hasItems,
  paymentError //-----> added this
}: props) => {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
  {!paymentError ? ( //----> added this. This line of code errors out
      {hasItems ? (
        <PaymentMessage />
      ) : (
        <AddItemsMessage />
      )}
):(  //-----> added this
      <Alerts
        errors={errors}
      />
) //-----> added this
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
```

Basically, i am taking one more input prop and modifying the way my JSX should look. But in this case, i am not able to add one boolean comparison one after the error. How do i make it working in this case. Any suggestions please ???

Comment: It looks like you're trying to implement nested ternary operators: `a ? b : c ? d : e` which translates as *if `a` is true then do `b`, else check if `c`is true and if so, do `d` and do `e` otherwise*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to create a function to handle this behavior. It's easier to read and to mantain

```
export const PayComponent = ({
  hasItems,
  paymentError
}: props) => {
  const RenderMessage = () => {
    if (hasItems) {
      if (paymentError) {
        return <PaymentMessage />
      }
      return <AddItemsMessage />
    }
    return <Alerts errors={errors}/>
  };

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <RenderMessage />
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
```